# Can't see view controller content after pushing to table view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new i iOS and Objective-C world, I want to create an example app to learn something but i find some problems in my program.

I Create a TableViewController with Books names, and after touch a book I want see a some more inforamtion about this book.

So I created book class what is a view controller, i created a some Labels inside this class with some text.

NSLogs works fine. After touch the record, apps pushing to new view controller from table view controller worsk good, but I can't see any content over there instead of white bg and back button at the top.

this is book class:

```
#import "BooksViewController.h"

@interface BooksViewController ()

@end

@implementation BooksViewController

- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{

    if(self){
        self.title = self.bookName;
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *bookNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    bookNameLabel.text = self.bookName;
    bookNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 50);
    [self.view addSubview:bookNameLabel];

    UILabel *authorNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    authorNameLabel.text = self.authorName;
    authorNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 40);
    [self.view addSubview:authorNameLabel];

    UILabel *bookDescLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    bookDescLabel.text = self.bookDesc;
    bookDescLabel.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 40);
    [self.view addSubview:bookDescLabel];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@end
```

this is a methods in table view controller witch I use to create a books inforamtion window:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];


        self.bookNames = @[@"Pan Tadeusz", @"Potop", @"Lalka", @"Uczta dla wron", @"Symfonnia C++"];
        self.authorsName = @[@"Adam Mickiewicz", @"Henryk Sienkiewicz", @"Bolesław Prus", @"George R.R Martin", @"Jerzy Greborz"];
        self.bookDescs = @[@"Opis Pan Tadeusz", @"Opis Potop", @"Opis Lalka", @"Opis Uczta dla wron", @"Opis Symfonnia C++"];


    }

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Książka na pozycji %ld tapped",indexPath.row);
    BooksViewController *bookVC = [[BooksViewController alloc] init];
    bookVC.bookName = self.bookNames[indexPath.row];
    bookVC.authorName = self.authorsName[indexPath.row];
    bookVC.bookDesc = self.bookDescs[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Nazwa wybranej książki: %@",bookVC.bookName);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:bookVC animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this wrong.

First, create an iVar that will save the Indexpath that the user selected, for that, simply add an `NSIndexPath` variable at the very top of your .m file.

```
@implementation yourControllerNameHere (){    //In your code you will have your controller name, just add the NSIndexpath ;)

    NSIndexPath *selectedPath;
}
```

You then need to perform a segue when you select a tableview cell, for that, replace your -`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method with this :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Książka na pozycji %ld tapped",indexPath.row);
    selectedPath = indexPath;  //We're saving the selected path to our instance variable ! This is very important otherwise we can't find it again.
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromBooksToDetail"];

}
```

and add the -prepareForSegue method in your .m file ; it should be there when you first created it ! just find it and add the following

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"fromBooksToDetail"]){

     BooksViewController *bookVC =(BooksViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
     bookVC.bookName    = self.bookNames[selectedPath.row];
     bookVC.authorName  = self.authorsName[selectedPath.row];
     bookVC.bookDesc    = self.bookDescs[selectedPath.row];
     NSLog(@"Nazwa wybranej książki: %@",bookVC.bookName);
   }  
}
```

Now this will NOT work unless you add a segue link between your two viewcontrollers in storyboard, so simply open your storyboard and, using a **right clic or a ctrl+left clic**, drag your mouse from your TableViewController to your BooksController. Don't forget to give it the right `identifier` in the `Attributes Inspector` on the right panel !

*Note that I wouldn't have named them like that ; BooksViewController has more sense if it's the `TableViewController` name, and "`BookDetailViewController`" for the detail page. But that's just a detail.*

Once you have the segue link, the `performSegue` call and the `prepareForSegue` method, you'll be all set ;)

Comment: I can't understant two things, why we should write `@interface yourControllerNameHere (){  ... } ` I have `@implementation` a the top so why ? and  Ok, I try rewrite every step, but there where I write a `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromBooksToDetail"];` appear a error - "No visible @interface for 'BooksTableViewController' declares the selector 'performSegueWithIndentifier:'

Comment: Did you create the segue link in your storyboard?

Comment: what that mean ? (I don't sepak english so weel, sorry)

Comment: Okay... Do you have a storyboard in your project? A file named **Main.storyboard**  ? You can search for it in your project file list, down at the bottom there is a search field.

Comment: To answer  your first comment, you can actually use `@implementation` instead of `@interface`, I typed without thinking. I'm changing it now

Comment: when I change a implementation to interface I have a problem with other methods like - (void)viewDidLoad, - (id)initWithNibName... etc

Comment: No no don't change to interface, I typed it wrong the first time. Keep implementation. NOT interface

Comment: You don't need to create an instance variable with the selected indexPath. Just pass the indexPath as a sender. (Or preferably an object holding the "Book" meta data)

Comment: That's true, I've never considered that. >_>

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to learn how to debug. Try putting `NSLog(@"bookname: %@", self.bookName)` in your `viewDidLoad` and see if you print anything. (Most probably not)
2. I'm not 100% sure how the view life cycle works when you use alloc init for a view controller. But my bet is that the properties are not set there. Try moving `bookNameLabel.text = self.bookName;` to `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`
3. You should use storyboards instead. It's super easy.

---

Also, your `initWithNibName` will never get called. You are using the `init`-method.